# Within C# is a loop declaration evaluated each time?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, evaluation

This is a really nit-picky question, but curiosity got the better of me.

Does a for loop re-evaluate the RHS condition each time the loop executes? See below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
}
```

Is it good practice throughout your code base to do the following?

```
for(int i = 0, n = collections.Count; i < n; i++)
{
}
```

Or does the compiler do these kind of optimisations / they're negligible (even with a huge code base)?

Comment: Second loop does not compile. Did you miss `; i < n;`?

Comment: Why not use `foreach` instead? Then there would be no worries about such optimizations.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Because you might not want to do something for each element?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi because perhaps you want to do something with the index

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for spotting that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The condition *will* be reevaluated before every iteration (unless the compiler detects that the condition is constant), and it is acceptable to write code that depends on this (such as calling a function whose return value will be different each time). Thus, if you have a condition that is expensive to evaluate and you are sure it will remain constant, it is indeed a good idea to evaluate it once, before the loop. However, for most standard collection types, `Count` is such a fast operation that the negligible performance gain won't be worth the reduced readability.

Comment: The type of `collection` isn't specified.  If it's declared as `IEnumerable<T>` and holds a reference to an implementation of `ICollection<T> or `ICollection`, `Count` will be somewhat slow; if it's declared as `IEnumerable<T>` and holds a reference to something that doesn't implement either of those particular generic types, even if it implements `IList<U>` for some `U` derived from `T`, `Count` may be very slow.

Comment: @supercat: True; I added a clarification about this.

Comment: @supercat If it was an `IEnumerable<T>` then it would be `Count()`, not `Count`.  While it's possible to have a property that's really slow, it would be *very* unusual; most likely you'd need to have a custom collection type that just does something really silly for it to be slow enough to be a problem.

Comment: @Servy: I'd missed that distinction.  Even with that distinction, the fact that a type implements `ICollection<T>` doesn't imply that `Count` will be as fast as a variable read.  For many types, it's apt to at minimum require a virtual method dispatch.  Further, in cases where a collection might have items appended during enumeration, code should be clear about whether the loop should include those items or not.

Comment: @supercat Yes, as I said, a custom collection could possibly do all sorts of evil things in a `Count` method that could be slow; the BCL collection types won't do that.  Attempting to remove a virtual dispatch is almost certainly a microoptimization that's not worth doing, and mutating a collection while enumerating it is a *very* bad idea; something that should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @Servy: There are a number of algorithms whose most logical implementation entails mutating a collection during enumeration; additionally, while there's no Framework list class which supports such a thing, there are some cases where it makes sense to have an `IList<T>` which supports thread-safe indexed-read and append operations, but not item removal (if `Count` returns 57, one will know that the 57 items at the start of the list will be there forevermore).  The fact that the Framework doesn't very well support such things does not mean they're not useful and appropriate.

Comment: @supercat While such an operation is not universally wrong, those situations are *very* unusual, and should be called out specifically.  The vast majority of collection iterations should not be done with that case in mind, because it's just such an edge case.

Comment: @Servy: If I see a `for` loop using a collection's `Count`, I'm going to wonder whether there's any particular reason it's not using `foreach`.  One of the most common reasons for such usage is to allow lists to be mutated while counting through them--something `foreach` won't allow.  As such, while I generally assume collections used in a `foreach` are not expected to change during enumeration, collections enumerated with `for` are another matter.  I would read code that re-polls `Count` as intending to have changes in length take effect immediately.

Comment: @supercat I find that the number of for loops over collections that mutate them to be very rare; most are simply using the index to do something, such as set the same index; access the item at the same index elsewhere, grab neighboring elements, etc.  I find that of the `for` loops that *don't* mutate the collection, virtually none of the pull out the count before the loop.  It seems like this is just  a personal convention that just you follow, that you're trying to apply to others, despite the fact that the general convention is the other way around.

Comment: @Servy: Again, it's probably a language thing.  I suspect if C# had a `for` loop which worked like the one in VB.NET, normal practice would be to use such a loop, thus sampling the count only once.

Answer (score 2):

if the right of the condition is constant (so it doesn't change in the loops internals) I believe the optimizer moves the collections.Count outside the top of the loop. If the collection is modified in the loop it would evaluated every-time.

if you used a foreach you will notice that you can't change the enumerator inside the loop because foreach uses this optimization to be a quicker loop....

You could always write a small demo app with a couple of loops one that modifies within the loop and one that doesn't and then run ildasm on it and see what code gets generated.